# How to build the "data" section of an $.ajax method in jQuery dynamically

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a reusable $.ajax method for my current application but I'm struggling to find solid information about how to build the **data:** section dynamically ...

Currently I'm looking at something similar to the function below, but I'm not sure how to implement this w/ jQuery 1.3.x (or if this type of thing was moved into the core?)

```
var extraParams = {
    timestamp: +new Date()
};

$.each(options.extraParams, function (key, param) {
    extraParams[key] = typeof param == "function" ? param() : param;
});
```

Comment: Hi Toran, any luck with any of these answers? You might want to pick one so this question gets marked answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this method as a wrapper so that I can send parameters. Also using the variables at the top of the method allows it to be minimized at a higher ratio and allows for some code reuse if making multiple similar calls.

```
function InfoByDate(sDate, eDate) {
    var divToBeWorkedOn = '#AjaxPlaceHolder';
    var webMethod = 'http://MyWebService/Web.asmx/GetInfoByDates'
    var parameters = "{'sDate':'" + sDate + "','eDate':'" + eDate + "'}"

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your question:

```
typeof param == "function" ? param() : param;
```

Should be written in current jQuery syntax as

```
$.isFunction(param) ? param() : param;
```

I hope that helps you build what you want.